# Best way to use test dependencies in Go but prevent export them

Tags: go, testing, go-modules

Given a project in Golang (1.14+) which is using test dependencies (like github.com/stretchr/testify) and now assume this project is a public library which can be used by others.

Usually when I now use `go mod graph` I'll always see this dependency like:

```
github.com/its-me/my-great-library@1.0.0
github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.6.1 github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.0
github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.6.1 github.com/pmezard/go-difflib@v1.0.0
github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.6.1 github.com/stretchr/objx@v0.1.0
github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.6.1 gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c
gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c gopkg.in/check.v1@v0.0.0-20161208181325-20d25e280405
```

`go mod tidy` or `go mod download` also seems to download all the test dependencies from the used lib. But instead of telling everybody to use `exclude` in their `go.mod` files is there a way to even prevent this been exported?

Comment: There is no difference between a "test dependency" and a "dependency". Also dependencies are not "exporter". What problem are you trying to solve and what is the actual question?

Comment: If it's an eyesore, move all `_test.go` to another package run your validations from there.

Comment: @Volker So far I assumed that there is no difference (following the documentation), but the hope is the last to die. I want to reduce the amount of stuff needs to be downloaded by people by using a public library. I'm (for my self) very often quite annoyed for libs where I have to download (on for example `go mod tidy`) at first some testing dependencies what I do not use and I do not want to use.

Comment: @colm.anseo your approach is not sexy but sounds plausible and the best option so far.

Comment: @GreNodge Did you find any solution for this problem? I am also facing the same.

Comment: @KishanB Not so far, unfortunately. As previously wrote: I try to live with it. :-/

Answer (score 13):

`go mod tidy` is intended to provide all of the dependencies needed to run `go test all`. Note that in Go 1.16, `go test all` will be somewhat less aggressive about *transitive* dependencies of tests (https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.16#all-pattern).

However, if your own test itself is using `testify`, then users of your package *will* need to download `testify` in order to run `go test all` in their own module.

(As colm.anseo notes, if you want you can split out the heavier tests to a separate package, so that when your users run `go test all` they will not run those tests and will not need to download the source code for those dependencies.)

Note that Go 1.17 adds support for [module graph pruning](https://golang.org/ref/mod#graph-pruning): if your module specifies `go 1.17` or higher and a consumer of your module does not use your test dependency in their own module, they will not need to download the source code or `go.mod` file for that dependency. (And once https://golang.org/issue/44435 is implemented, when they run `go mod download` it will not download the irrelevant dependency either.)